# logging in multiple classes with module name in log

Tags: python, logging, namespaces

I want to use the logging module instead of printing for debug information and documentation.
The goal is to print on the console with DEBUG level and log to a file with INFO level.

I read through a lot of documentation, the cookbook and other tutorials on  the logging module but couldn't figure out, how I can use it the way I want it. (I'm on python25)

I want to have the names of the modules in which the logs are written in my logfile.

The documentation says I should use `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` but how do I declare the loggers used in classes in other modules / packages, so they use the same handlers like the main logger? To recognize the 'parent' I can use `logger = logging.getLogger(parent.child)` but where do I know, who has called the class/method?`

The example below shows my problem, if I run this, the output will only have the `__main__` logs in and ignore the logs in `Class`

This is my **Mainfile:**

```
# main.py

import logging
from module import Class

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create file handler which logs info messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('foo.log', 'w', 'utf-8')
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create console handler with a debug log level
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# creating a formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('- %(name)s - %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s')

# setting handler format
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info('Script starts')
    logger.info('calling class Class')
    c = Class()
    logger.info('calling c.do_something()')
    c.do_something()
    logger.info('calling c.try_something()')
    c.try_something()
```

**Module:**

```
# module.py

imnport logging

class Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # What do I have to enter here?
        self.logger.info('creating an instance of Class')
        self.dict = {'a':'A'}
    def do_something(self):
        self.logger.debug('doing something')
        a = 1 + 1
        self.logger.debug('done doing something')
    def try_something(self):
        try:
            logging.debug(self.dict['b'])
        except KeyError, e:
            logging.exception(e)
```

Output in **console:**

```
- __main__ - INFO    : Script starts
- __main__ - INFO    : calling class Class
- __main__ - INFO    : calling c.do_something()
- __main__ - INFO    : calling c.try_something()
No handlers could be found for logger "module"
```

Besides: Is there a way to get the module names were the logs ocurred in my logfile, without declaring a new logger in each class like above? Also like this way I have to go for `self.logger.info()` each time I want to log something. I would prefer to use `logging.info()` or `logger.info()` in my whole code.

Is a global logger perhaps the right answer for this? But then I won't get the modules where the errors occur in the logs...

And my last question: Is this pythonic? Or is there a better recommendation to do such things right.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your main module, you're configuring the logger of name `'__main__'` (or whatever `__name__` equates to in your case) while in module.py you're using a different logger. You either need to configure loggers per module, or you can configure the root logger (by configuring `logging.getLogger()`) in your main module which will apply by default to all loggers in your project.

I recommend using configuration files for configuring loggers. This link should give you a good idea of good practices: http://victorlin.me/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python

EDIT: use %(module) in your formatter to include the module name in the log message.

Comment: If I configure the root logger, how will see where the logs were created in the log file? then everywhere there just says 'root'.

Comment: I edited my answer to include adding the module name in the message.

Comment: Configuring just the root logger is acceptable as long as you wish to apply the same settings to all loggers across your project. However, if you need to add different handlers based on modules then it's a better idea to define a good clear configuration file and specify package level logger (e.g. logger configs for path.to.package1 will apply to all children of this package hierarchy)

Comment: I really missunderstood the meaning of the (name) formatter, as I thought, it would display me where the log is created. Reading through that much code examples and everyone used it similar... Thanks though for making me realize this was the wrong path. I will just use the basicConfig() now, so I can use just logging.info() in my classes without self and without declaring any new logger. THANKS!

Comment: Is it possible, to add the package name to the module too, or even the class name? just the module name isn't that helpful if you got a really big project...

Comment: if you use `logger.getLogger(__name__)` then you will get the full module name (including the package hierarchy) in the log message (provided you have the `%(name)` formatter element). Remember, if the root logger is configured then it will apply to all children (meaning all packages and modules).

Comment: So how do i have to make this if i want to use the `logging.getLogger(__name__)` variant? What do I have to enter at the line in my Class?

Comment: If you just remove `__name__` from the getLogger call in your main.py module above, everything should work as you wanted without any other modifications (since you'll be configuring the root logger which applies to all children including module.py). Try it and you should understand what I mean.

Answer (score 11):

The generally recommended logging setup is having at most 1 logger per module.

If your project is [properly packaged](https://packaging.python.org/), `__name__` will have the value of `"mypackage.mymodule"`, except in your main file, where it has the value `"__main__"`

If you want more context about the code that is logging messages, note that you can set your formatter with a [formatter string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) like `%(funcName)s`, which will add the function name to all messages.

If you **really** want per-class loggers, you can do something like:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__+"."+self.__class__.__name__)
```

Comment: Hm... this just looks soo awful, when I have to insert the name in each class explicitly... There has to be a better way

Comment: I found out, that it just helps to get rid of the `getLogger(__name__)` in my main file. when I use `''` there and the `__name__` in the module, everything is displayed fine!

Comment: @drrtyrokka Ideally, you should avoid using `getLogger('')` - other modules from libraries you're using might end up using the root logger too, and they can then change your handlers and formatters configuration. It's safer to simply use a project-wide prefix

Comment: But now it doesn't work anymore... so I really have to use you're version with `'myapp.'+__name__` every single time...

Comment: @drrtyrokka loggers, if not assigned handlers, will use their parent's. If you don't use `'parentloggername+'.'+'childloggername'`, `logging` thinks they are independent (i.e.: not parent/child)

Comment: @uloco You may exploit decorator to add a logger to a class for you: https://xmedeko.blogspot.cz/2017/10/python-logger-by-class.html